# javascript logout confirm on website

Tags: javascript, web

i try to make a confirmation of logout in my web. but if the link i click. there is not reaction. just refresh it. this is my script :

```
    <script language="javascript">
<!--
function konfirmasi()
{
    tanya=confirm("are you sure?")
    if (tanya != '0')
    {
        top.location.href="logout.php";
    }
}
//-->
</script>
```

and this is my html script:

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none " title="Keluar" onclick="konfirmasi()"><img src="./img/guestbook.png" border="0"><b><font face="verdana" size="2" color="#FF0000">Logout</font></b></a>
```

whats wrong on my script?

Comment: did you tried by adding a debugger in your javascript?

Comment: it is working as expected see here http://jsfiddle.net/4FMVn/

Comment: I think PSR right, you just need '#' to href, try :
http://jsfiddle.net/4FMVn/1/

Comment: Why are you writing HTML 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much everything :

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of :

```
<script language="javascript"></script>
```

---

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 2px;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

And :

```
<a href="#" title="Keluar" onclick="konfirmasi()">
    <img alt="Alternative text" src="./img/guestbook.png" />
    Logout
</a>
```

Instead of :

```
<a href="" style="text-decoration:none " title="Keluar" onclick="konfirmasi()"><img src="./img/guestbook.png" border="0"><b><font face="verdana" size="2" color="#FF0000">Logout</font></b></a>
```

---

```
if(window.confirm("Are you sure ?"))
{
    window.open('logout.php', '_self');
}
```

Instead of :

```
tanya=confirm("are you sure?")
if (tanya != '0')
{
    top.location.href="logout.php";
}
```

---

Clear and standard code is a good place to start BEFORE starting to look for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script language="text/javascript"> // note the "text/javascript"

function konfirmasi()
{
    var tanya = confirm("are you sure?");

    if (tanya == true)
    {
        window.location.href = "logout.php"; // .location is part of the window object
    }
}

</script>
```

Your HTML also needs a # in the href, else it won't work for some devices. So it would look like this:

```
<a href="#" style="text-decoration:none " title="Keluar" onclick="konfirmasi();"><img src="./img/guestbook.png" border="0"><b><font face="verdana" size="2" color="#FF0000">Logout</font></b></a>
```